# How to do MVC with JavaFX and scenebuilder?

Tags: javafx

What's the right way to implement MVC when using scenebuilder? The main problem is all the @FXML variables, for example a TextField

```
@FXLM TextField textField;
```

How would you talk to the textfield through other classes? Am I approaching it wrong?

Comment: Your view should observe the model. Use the controller to establish the connection, if necessary. Nothing but the controller should even be aware of the existence of the `TextField`.

Comment: Is there any guide I could read on this ?